# Nothing happens when button is clicked in Android App

Tags: java, android, button, click

I'm having trouble getting a button to work in a fragment I'm working on. Here is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


//create button listener for player match
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MatchButton);
    Log.v("LOADING MATCH", "TEST");

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.v("LOADING MATCH", "TEST2");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplay.class);
            String message = "test";
            intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

MatchButton is defined in the fragment XML here:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Match to Player"
        android:id="@+id/MatchButton"/>
```

The app loads fine, but when I click the button, nothing happens. Any Ideas? I'm fairly new to this, so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change return of `onCreateView` to :

```
return rootView;
```

Problem is occurring because setting click listener for Button and return view object from `onCreateView` both is different object's.

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed the issue... totally forgot to change the return after defining the rootview.